# How to get more detailed error messages from Azure Functions JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, diagnostics, serverless

I'm running Node.js functions on Azure Functions on the v2 of the runtime and quite often running the function ends up in an error. But debugging the errors is really difficult since most of the time only thing I get is something like this:

```
2018-04-19T18:08:51  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-04-19T18:09:37.473 [Information] Executing 'Functions.GetAnswer' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=82d8e1df-7bb8-4f08-80c9-1d27d68959e2)
2018-04-19T18:09:37.788 [Error] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.GetAnswer. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Worker process with pid 4736 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 5328 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 5428 exited with code 1). Worker process with pid 4736 exited with code 1.
2018-04-19T18:09:37.937 [Error] Executed 'Functions.GetAnswer' (Failed, Id=82d8e1df-7bb8-4f08-80c9-1d27d68959e2)
```

When using App Insights I don't get much more info:

```
Exception while executing function:
Functions.GetAnswer One or more errors occurred.
(Worker process with pid 4736 exited with code 1)
(Worker process with pid 5328 exited with code 1)
(Worker process with pid 5428 exited with code 1)
Worker process with pid 4736 exited with code 1
Worker process with pid 5328 exited with code 1
Worker process with pid 5428 exited with code 1
```

Is there a way to get an error message that would show more about what is going on? Maybe even a Node.js error?

Comment: Unfortunately, not right now :,( Coming soon!! https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/51

Comment: Ok! Sad to hear that but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set all logging levels to `verbose` in your `host.json`:

```
{
    "tracing": {
        "consoleLevel": "verbose"
    },
    "logger": {
        "categoryFilter": {
            "defaultLevel": "verbose",
            "categoryLevels": {
                "Host.Results": "verbose",
                "Function": "verbose",
                "Host.Aggregator": "verbose"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then check whether it gives you more information, but this specific error in related to rather internal part of Azure Functions runtime, and it'll be hard to investigate if you don't provide you function's code.

Comment: I tried consoleLevel: verbose already but it did nothing. Might try the rest of those, but like Marie answered above, it does not seem to be possible to get the Node.js errors out at the moment.

Comment: @mattipet That's unfortunate.